# cocos2d process events randomly while animating

Tags: python-3.x, cocos2d-python

This problem is so weird that I think I'm doing a huge mistake somewhere.

I'm using cocos2d in python3. I created a simple example, which basically is a merge of `samples/hello_world.py` and `samples/handling_events.py`, and just visualize a moving text while also checking for events.

Problem is: events are processed basically randomly while the animation is in progress: sometimes, pressing ESC, the program stops after few instants, sometimes it doesn't stop. Pressing the keyboard usually doesn't show anything in the text, but if you press a lot of keys maybe you get a couple to get visualized. Same with the mouse: if you move or click a lot, sometimes you see the event processed.

I can't understand what's happening: isn't cocos supposed to process the events before every rendered frame? Am I missing something?

Source code

```
import cocos
import pyglet
from cocos.actions import *

class HelloWorld(cocos.layer.ColorLayer):
    def __init__(self):
        super(HelloWorld, self).__init__(64, 64, 200, 255)

        label = cocos.text.Label(
            'Hello, World!',
            font_name='Times New Roman',
            font_size=32,
            anchor_x='center',
            anchor_y='center')

        label.position = (320, 240)
#       label.scale = 2 # Pixel scale
        self.add(label)

        scale = ScaleBy(3, duration=2)
        # Unlimited repeat
        #label.do(Repeat(scale + Reverse(scale)))
        # Limited repeat
        label.do((scale + Reverse(scale)) * 3)

class KeyDisplay(cocos.layer.Layer):
    # This is necessary to receive events
    is_event_handler = True

    def __init__(self):
        super(KeyDisplay, self).__init__()

        self.text = cocos.text.Label('', x=100, y=200)
        self.down_keys_ = set()
        self.update_text()
        self.add(self.text)

    def update_text(self):
        key_names = [pyglet.window.key.symbol_string(k) for k in self.down_keys_]
        self.text.element.text = 'Keys: ' + ' '.join(key_names)

    def on_key_press(self, key, modifiers):
        self.down_keys_.add(key)
        self.update_text()

    def on_key_release(self, key, modifiers):
        self.down_keys_.remove(key)
        self.update_text()

class MouseDisplay(cocos.layer.Layer):
    is_event_handler = True

    def __init__(self):
        super(MouseDisplay, self).__init__()

        self.text = cocos.text.Label('', x=100, y=150)
        self.add(self.text)

    def on_mouse_motion(self, x, y, dx, dy):
        self.text.element.text = 'Moving'
    def on_mouse_drag(self, x, y, dx, dy, buttons, modifiers):
        self.text.element.text = 'Dragging'
    def on_mouse_press(self, x, y, buttons, modifiers):
        self.text.element.text = 'Pressed'
    def on_mouse_release(self, x, y, buttons, modifiers):
        self.text.element.text = 'Released'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cocos.director.director.init()
    # A layer with text
    hello_layer = HelloWorld()
    hello_layer.do(RotateBy(360 * 2, duration=5))
    # A layer for key
    key_layer = KeyDisplay()
    # A layer for mouse
    mouse_layer = MouseDisplay()

    main_scene = cocos.scene.Scene(hello_layer, key_layer, mouse_layer)
    cocos.director.director.run(main_scene)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was due to a bug in pyglet.

For details:

- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cocos-discuss/6uviIoGzII8
- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pyglet-users/uG_qgulsixI